# How to get a Mongoose model by collection name?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Collection is `chats`.
Model name is `Chat`.

```
import {model, Schema} from 'mongoose';
const ChatSchema = new Schema(
    {
        username: {type: String, required: true, index: true},
        message: {type: String, required: true},
    }
);
export default model('Chat', ChatSchema);
```

I can get the model via `mongoose.model('Chat')` just fine.

*But*, is there a way to get the `Chat` model **by the collection name** `chats`?

Comment: I guess it should possible via [MongooseNames](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-modelNames) method

Comment: Nope, that's modelNames and model name is "Chat" which is different from collection name "chats"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the collection name in schema too:

```
const ChatSchema = new Schema(
    {
        username: {type: String, required: true, index: true},
        message: {type: String, required: true},
    },
    { collection: 'chats' } // <-- here
);
```

[Reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection)

Comment: That is not an answer to my question.